# Finding the best preposition for a verb

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I have the task of sentence completion, I have the subj, verb, adverb or subject and all I need is the appropriate preposition in between. Is there any NLP tool that can give distribution over the prepositions that can go with the verb?

Best

Comment: This is about English text, right? Prepositions are a closed class, which means you can create a complete list of all prepositions (which you can't for nouns or verbs). If you know where the open slot is, you can just fill in each of them and use a language model to compare the perplexity of the whole sentence for each candidate. This is, of course, a brute-force method, I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to get frequency counts for all verb-preposition pairs in the Brown corpus, and then look up the ones for the verb "go". First the counts:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
prepchoices = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((v[0], p[0]) 
    for (v, p) in nltk.bigrams(brown.tagged_words(tagset="universal")) 
        if v[1] == "VERB" and p[1] == "ADP")
```

"ADP" stands for "adposition", i.e. preposition or post-position. Now let's look at what we've got:

```
>>> prepchoices["go"]
FreqDist({'to': 96, 'with': 20, 'into': 18, 'through': 8, 'on': 8, 'for': 7, 
'in': 5, 'out': 4, 'around': 4, 'from': 4, ...})
```

You can get the top choices, in descending order of frequency, with `most_common()`:

```
>>> print(prepchoices["go"].most_common(5))
[('to', 96), ('with', 20), ('into', 18), ('through', 8), ('on', 8)]
```

I didn't do any stemming of the verbs ("goes" and "went" were counted as separate words), or even case-folding. You could add them, but the above should already give you a decent picture of the distribution.

Comment: That is really helpful. Is there anyway to use if with trigrams and find the word in between?

Comment: Now you're changing the question! You specifically asked for "distribution over the prepositions that can go with the verb". Given a list `triples = [(v1, prep1, n1), (v2, prep2, n2), ...]`, you could construct the distribution like this: `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(((v, n), prep) for v, prep, n in triples)`. Now the `(v, n)` tuples are keys. BUT (a) you will need *a lot* more data to get a reliable distribution, and (b) usually the noun doesn't immediately follow the prep, so you'll have to do the work of finding it. My prediction is that it's better to ignore the noun and just use the above.

Comment: If you **really** need the noun, I'd build a separate `(noun, prep)` conditional distribution table and use both of them to calculate frequencies for completion. You'll still need to find the nouns following each prep in the training corpus, though. Anyway you now know how to apply the `nltk` to your problem. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of NLTK being useful, but I am sure you can find a lot of public Github repos if you search. Some results that come up are TextBlob, Standard Core NLP, spaCy, genism.

Comment: I have looked into those libraries but I dont know if they provide preposition -verb relations